# Wordpress functions in wordpress functions and escape characters

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying use the [edit_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link) function to contain an image. All of the quotations and parameters are driving me crazy... How can I get this to work?

This outputs **Edit** inside the anchor link for editing the post.

```
<?php edit_post_link(__("**Edit**"), ''); ?>
```

This outputs the image I want to use.

```
<?php echo "<img src=\"" ?>
<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory')?>
<?php echo "/images/edit.png\" />" ?>
```

I've tried tons of configurations, this is the latest, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php edit_post_link(__(" <img src=\" " bloginfo('template_directory') " /images/edit.png\" /> "), ''); ?>
```

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: I keep getting an error something involving t-string. I just know I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
<?php edit_post_link('<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/edit.png" />', '', ''); ?>
```

or

```
<?php edit_post_link(get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/edit.png', '<img src="', '" />'); ?>
```

should work

references:

[get_bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo), because only bloginfo() is an echo, get_bloginfo() a return value

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `get_edit_post_link()` instead? It should return just the URL.